# How to compare theoretic efficiency with practice examples

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance

I've written a C++ code to solve a specific problem, and I've studied efficiency (theoretic efficiency, big O).

I'm interested in comparing that efficiency I've calculated, with some practical examples, testing my algorithm, in order to see if I did the calculations correctly.

Is there any way to do it? Should I get execution times? Then, how can I compare it to that big-O that I've calculated?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: What difference would you expect between the execution time of an algorithm with `O(n)` when doubling `n`?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://quick-bench.com/.
Or you could write your own benchmark software.

Comment: double? I don't know. It depends also of the input data (in this algorithm, at least)

Comment: @UnholySheep I wouldn't expect it to double at all.  There could be a constant in there which won't change  :P

Comment: If big-O is O(n) then it really should double, if its running time depends not only on n, then theoretical formula should be different.

Comment: @Yola Consider `k * n + m`, where `k` is a small constant and `m` is a large constant. This is O(n), but for sufficiently small n, the difference when doubling `n` is negligible.

Comment: A corollary to @molbdnilo's observation: Because all the computers that can be built are finite, there will always be algorithms where `n` is constrained to be "sufficiently small"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run your implementation with input data of different sizes and measure how much time it takes to run on these sizes.

Say, you chose sizes 100, 200, 1000. Suppose you ran several times for every input size and calculated an averages - T<sub>100</sub>, T<sub>200</sub>, T<sub>1000</sub>. Now calculate T<sub>200</sub>/T<sub>100</sub> and check with your theoretical complexity. Does it grow with the same speed? E.g. if theoretical complexity is O(n) then time should nearly double.

Answer (score -1):

[Google Benchmark can calculate asymptotic complexity](https://github.com/google/benchmark#calculate-asymptotic-complexity-big-o) (i.e. Big-O) for you. There is also [this](http://quick-bench.com/) web service that can help you quickly benchmark code snippets with exactly this framework. But you should obviously be considerate with how much computation you request from the latter.